# Question shows 1 Answer, but no actual Answers shown

Tags: support, answers

[ListView isn't resizing when keyboard is shown](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5608806/listview-isnt-resizing-when-keyboard-is-shown)

The above question shows an Answer count of 1, but no answers as shown. Why?

Comment: There was a spam answer that was deleted, the answer count probably hasn't caught up yet

Comment: To expand on Yi Jiang: like much else on SO, answer counts are cached for performance, so they don't always reflect true numbers.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, a spam answer was bulk deleted from the question.

Answer counts are re-normalized every 24 hours for exceptional cases like this.

Comment: Thanks. How can you tell it was a deleted spam answer? Is it something I'm not seeing because I don't have enough rep?

Comment: @Kenny: yes, exactly. [At 10k rep, you can see deleted answers](http://stackoverflow.com/privileges/moderator-tools).